# My program is not able to locate the locator for submit button when anather captcha comes

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, selenium-webdriver

So I am making automation program to download CSV files from a website which keeps getting revised in around 5 min interval. The website has captcha based system, and I am using tesseract OCR to bypass it. The output of captcha needs to be entered in a captcha box, and then again we have to select the file type to download. After selecting filetype, another captcha diaolog box comes and we have to enter captcha text here also. I have automated the process of entering both the captchas, but in second captcha selenium could not locate the submit button. It locates the first Submit button in first captcha but not in second one.

Here is the code to click the first click button:

```
submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button\[contains(@class, 'btn-success') and contains(@class, 'ui-button-text') and contains(., 'Submit Captcha')\]")))
submit_button.click()
```

And the second one which is:

```
submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button\[contains(@class, 'btn-success') and contains(@class, 'ui-button-text') and contains(., 'Submit Captcha')\]")))
submit_button.click()
```

I don't know what O am doing wrong.

Here is the inspect output of button in html.

```
\<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"\>\<span class="ui-button-text"\>Submit Captcha\</span\>\</button\>

here is the inspect output of captcha dialog box<br>\<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="position: absolute; height: auto; width: 400px; top: 104px; left: 475px; display: block;" aria-describedby="ShowCaptchaBox" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2"\>\<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"\>\<span id="ui-id-2" class="ui-dialog-title"\>Validate Captcha\</span\>\<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close"\>\<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"\>\</span\>\<span class="ui-button-text"\>close\</span\>\</button\>\</div\>\<div id="ShowCaptchaBox" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 126px;"\>\<div class="widget-body"\>\<div class="widget-toolbox"\>\<div class="btn-toolbar"\>\<img src="/CustomCaptcha/ReportCaptchaIndex?timestamp=1711349475570"\>\<br\>\<br\>\<input type="text" name="captchaValue" id="txtCaptcha"\>\<br\>\<br\>\</div\>\<br\>\</div\>\</div\>\</div\>\<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix"\>\<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"\>\<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"\>\<span class="ui-button-text"\>Submit Captcha\</span\>\</button\>\</div\>\</div\>\<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;"\>\</div\>\<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"\>\</div\>\<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"\>\</div\>\<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"\>\</div\>\<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"\>\</div\>\<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90;"\>\</div\>\<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90;"\>\</div\>\<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90;"\>\</div\>\</div\>
```

PLease help I am stuck.

I tried different selectors xpath, css, class selectors. Nothing works. Output is alwas timeoutexception from selnium
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

```
Stacktrace:
GetHandleVerifier \[0x00007FF707C87062+63090\]
(No symbol) \[0x00007FF707BF2CB2\]
```